# ECS on Fargate scale down issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a small project for school and test ECS on Fargate and autoscaling with custom metrics. I have created an application that will push custom metrics to CloudWatch and the ScaleUP is working, but it doesn't scale down.

CloudWatch Logs and Alarms:

```
########################################################################################################################

## Create log group for our service

########################################################################################################################

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "log_group" {
name              = "/${lower(var.namespace)}/ecs/${lower(var.service_name)}"
retention_in_days = var.retention_in_days

    tags = {
        scenariu = var.scenariu
    }

}

########################################################################################################################

## Define CloudWatch Metric Alarm for numberofrequests

########################################################################################################################

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "numberofrequests_scale_up_alarm" {
alarm_name          = "${var.namespace}_NumberOfRequestsScaleUpAlarm_${var.environment}"
comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
evaluation_periods  = 2
metric_name         = "numberofrequests"
namespace           = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log_group.name  # Replace with the actual CloudWatch Log Group name
period              = 30  # Adjust as needed
statistic           = "Average"
threshold           = 10  # Adjust as needed

    dimensions = {
    }
    
    alarm_actions = [
    aws_appautoscaling_policy.ecs_custom_increase_policy.arn,
    ]

}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "numberofrequests_scale_down_alarm" {
alarm_name          = "${var.namespace}_NumberOfRequestsScaleDownAlarm_${var.environment}"
comparison_operator = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"  # Adjust to your specific condition
evaluation_periods  = 2
metric_name         = "numberofrequests"
namespace           = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log_group.name  # Replace with the actual CloudWatch Log Group name
period              = 30  # Adjust as needed
statistic           = "Average"
threshold           = 9  # Adjust as needed

    dimensions = {
    }
    
    alarm_actions = [
        aws_appautoscaling_policy.ecs_custom_decrease_policy.arn,
    ]

}
```

ECS Autoscaling

```
########################################################################################################################

## Define Target Tracking on ECS Cluster Task level

########################################################################################################################

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
max_capacity       = var.ecs_task_max_count
min_capacity       = var.ecs_task_min_count
resource_id        = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.default.name}/${aws_ecs_service.service.name}"
scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
service_namespace  = "ecs"
}

########################################################################################################################

## Policy for custom metric tracking; number of requests

########################################################################################################################

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_custom_increase_policy" {
name                          = "${var.namespace}_CustomIncreaseTargetTrackingScaling_${var.environment}"
resource_id                    = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
scalable_dimension             = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension
service_namespace              = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace
policy_type                    = "StepScaling"

    step_scaling_policy_configuration {
        adjustment_type               = "ChangeInCapacity"
        metric_aggregation_type       = "Average"
    
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
      metric_interval_upper_bound = 10
      scaling_adjustment           = 1  # Increase by 1 instance
    }
    
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = 10
      scaling_adjustment           = 1  # Increase by 1 instance
    }

}
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_custom_decrease_policy" {
name                          = "${var.namespace}_CustomDecreaseTargetTrackingScaling_${var.environment}"
policy_type                    = "StepScaling"
resource_id                    = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
scalable_dimension             = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension
service_namespace              = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace

    step_scaling_policy_configuration {
        adjustment_type               = "ChangeInCapacity"
        metric_aggregation_type       = "Average"
    
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = 10
      # metric_interval_upper_bound = 10
      scaling_adjustment           = -1  # Decrease by 1 instance
    }

}
}
```

The Alarms work. If I have requests the scaleup alarm will be in alarm state, and if I don't have requests the scale down alert will be in alarm

As mentioned, the ScaleUp is working, but the ScaleDown is not, do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

I've tried changing the values of the scaling and alarms but still the same problem.

Comment: I solved this by finding this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/step-scaling-policy-overview.html and updating metric_interval_lower_bound metric_interval_upper_bound for the decrease     step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = -10
      metric_interval_upper_bound = 0
      scaling_adjustment           = -1  # Decrease by 1 instance
    }

    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_upper_bound = -10
      scaling_adjustment           = -1  # Decrease by 1 instance